# Random Presentation Topic Picker returns null

Tags: java, random, generator

Today my teacher asked me to program a random presentation topic picker for him.

The idea was, that the student goes to the pc and clicks on the message Dialog which then randomly generates a number between 1 and the max index of the topics and then prints the according topic.

I tried it with HashMaps.  to put in the key that stays with the String together so that I can then (after the output) remove that entry so that no other student can get the same topic.

But it always returns at least 1 empty reference -> null.

Here is the code:

```
static HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args){

    int anzahlEintraege = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Wie viele Themen gibt es?"));

    for(int i = 0; i < anzahlEintraege; i++){
        map.put((i+1),JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Geben Sie das Thema Nummer " + (i+1) + " ein!"));
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jetzt geht's Los!");

    int max = map.size();
    int removed = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++){
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = r.nextInt(max-1)+1;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sie haben das Thema "+ map.get(random) + " gezogen!");
        map.remove(random);
        removed++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Do not remove random. When it is picked as a random once again, you have no item for it in your map, so you have null.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is that you can pick the same random number more than once, even if you've already removed the element with that key.

Instead of trying to pick non-duplicating random numbers, you would be better off to simply create a list of your keys, randomize their order, and then simply iterate over them.

Here's a simple example using strings that you should be able to adapt:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1, "foo");
        map.put(2, "bar");
        map.put(3, "baz");

        List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
        Collections.shuffle(keys);

        for (Integer key : keys) {
            String randomValue = map.get(key);
            System.out.println(randomValue);
        }
    }
}
```